# What is the difference between int * and int a[size]

Tags: c

```
Case I: 
   int a[12];
   printf("%d",sizeof(a));

Case II:
    int *a = (int *)malloc(12*sizeof(int));
    printf("%d",sizeof(a));
```

The above two code snippets return different outputs,

- `48` in the first case
- `4` in the second case

Why is it so?

Comment: Does [Is an array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c/1641963#1641963) make a suitable duplicate?  A search on '[c] array pointer' yields 33,000 or so entries, which is a tad painful to search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because arrays are not pointers and vice-versa. Period.

To elaborate, in case of  `int a[12];`, `a` is an array, which has got it's own properties. It is of type *array*, so when you pass the array name to `sizeof` operator, it gives you the size of the *array* (in your case, 12 `int`s, multiplied by size of an `int`, 4, total 48).

OTOH, `int *a = malloc(12*sizeof*a);` (corrected format), `a` is a pointer, and using `sizeof` on this will give you only the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the memory allocated (*pointed by*) to the pointer.

To quote the C-faq, chapter 6,

> **Q: But I heard that `char a[]` was identical to `char *a`?**
>
> A: Not at all. (What you heard has to do with formal parameters to functions). Arrays are not pointers, though they are closely related.
>
> The array declaration `char a[6]` requests that space for six characters be set aside, to be known by the name `a`. That is, there is a location named `a` at which six characters can sit. The pointer declaration `char *p`, on the other hand, requests a place which holds a pointer, to be known by the name `p`. This pointer can point almost anywhere: to any `char`, or to any contiguous array of `chars`, or nowhere.

Notes:

1. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. To make your code robust and portable, prefer using the variable name itself instead of the hard-coded datatype in the allocation statement.

Comment: That period felt so powerful :D  Plus for short and concise answer, but i believe this question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Transcendental Thanks. Only wish that value of _period_ would have been understood by all. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh  a[i] is the same as *(a+i) rite? so then why are they different datatypes apologies but a link that explains arrays and pointers would be of good help

Comment: @AAB I think you're mixing up the point. Both the representations will give you the same result, but here we're talking about the type. Hope it's clear.

Comment: well I understand they are separate data types but when an operation is done internally a[i] gets converted to *(a+i) rite? so what actually happens here can you throw some light

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and pointers are different datatypes in C. When array is used as an operand with `sizeof` operator , it gives the size of array data type. But, when a pointer is used with `sizeof` operator, size of pointer is returned.

Standard says (C11-6.5.3.4):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**.

The type of operand `a` in first case is `int [12]` while the type of operand in second case is `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different answers because in the two cases `a` is different.

`int a[12];` — in this `a` is an array,

`int *a = malloc(12*sizeof*a);` — in this `a` is a pointer.

---

Pointers and arrays can be used interchangeably at most of the places, but that does not mean they are the same things. Both have different properties (as explained by Sourav).

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` operator deals with the size of **type**. *It does not have to do anything with the contents held by the operands passed to it*.

`int a[12]` as a type `int [12]` and therefore give size `48(4*12)`.

But `int *a` is an integer pointer and `sizeof` operator give size of the pointer (*i.e* `4`).

Both in these cases `int a[12]` and `int *a` are not same.
Note that `sizeof` is one of the few cases where an array does not decay to a pointer.